if $f \circ f \circ f \circ f \circ f(x)=x $ then $f(x)=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$
Let $f \in \mathbb{F}_{7^r}(x)$ (field of rational functions over the finite field with $7^r$ elements) satisfying $$f \circ f \circ f \circ f \circ f(x)=x$$
Show that exist $A,B,C$ and $D$ such that $$f(x)=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$$
My attempt: If $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, with $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ coprimes, then it is known that the deegre of extension of $\mathbb{F}_{7^r}(x)/\mathbb{F}_{7^r}(f)$ is $\max\{\deg(p),\deg(q)\}$. Note that if $\max\{\deg(p),\deg(q)\}=1$, then $f(x)=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$. So, I showed that I proved that $x \in \mathbb{F}_{7^r}(f)$.
To see this, note that $$f \in \mathbb{F}_{7^r}(x) \implies f \circ f \circ f \circ f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{7^r}(x) \implies f \circ f \circ f \circ f(f(x)) \in \mathbb{F}_{7^r}(f) \implies x \in \mathbb{F}_{7^r}(f)   $$
Is it well done? I don't know where the importance of $7^r$. Moreover, I am asked to find the minimum value of r for the above to be true.

If $C\neq0$, then what happens with $x=-D/C$?

HINT.-$A,B,C,D$ are elements of $\mathbb F_{7^r}$ and if $f(x)=\dfrac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$   then there is the reciprocal function $f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{-Dx+B}{Cx-A}$ and
$$f^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \circ f^{-1}(x)=x$$

What do you mean with "Find the minimum value for the above to be true"? I am guessing you mean that you need to find the minimum $r$ for which there is an element in $\mathbb{F}{7^r}$ with $f^5=x$. Do you know of the connection between linear rational functions and the group $\operatorname{PGL}(\mathbb{F}{7^r})$? That would make things easier for you.

@2'5 9'2 Rational functions are usually seen as maps from $K\cup{\infty}$ to itself and the value $-D/C$ is mapped to $\infty$.

And btw, your proof is correct as it is. However, you could include some more details.

@schiepy I was not familiar with doing this over a finite field, where $\infty$ has no geometric meaning (that I can see). So $f(-D/C)=\infty$, and $f(\infty)=A/C$ when $C\neq0$? And when $C=0$, $f(\infty)=\infty$?

Your proof of the fact is indeed correct. The number $7^r$ only becomes relevant when asked what the minimal $r$ is for which there is an element $f\in \mathbb{F}_{7^r}(x)$ such that $f^5=x$. By what you showed earlier we know that such $f$ is a linear rational function. Linear rational functions under composition are isomorphic to the group $PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_{7^r})$, which has order $(7^r-1)7^r(7^r+1)$. By Cauchy's theorem there is an element of order $p$ ($p$ prime) in the finite group $G$ if and only if $p\mid \#G$. Note that $5\nmid 6\cdot 7\cdot 8$ but $5\mid (7^2-1)\cdot 7^2\cdot (7^2+1)$, hence the minimal $r$ for which there is such an element is $r=2$.
If you want to explicitly find an element of order $5$ you can do the following: Take a generator $\gamma$ of $\mathbb{F}_{7^4}^{\ast}$ and calculate its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{7^2}$, which is of degree $2$. Take the companion matrix $A$ of this polynomial. It can be shown that $A^{7^4-1}=1$ and if considered as an element of $PGL(\mathbb{F}_{7^2})$ it is of order $7^2+1$. Raise $[A]\in PGL(\mathbb{F}_{7^2})$ to the $(7^2+1)/5$ and you are done. Convert to a linear rational function via $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ if you want.
